# OpenERP7, new user with full rights unable to create new partners

Tags: configuration, odoo, rights

With the admin user I can do everything, add, delete, modify, etc. As it should be.

Then using this user added a new one, with full access to sales and accounting options as some other ones needed for sales operations. Then tried to add a new supplier and it throws a warning:

```
Access Denied
The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions.
Please contact your system administrator.
(Document type: Pricelist, Operation: read)
```

Tested all the possible combinations on user rights and ended up giving full access to all options. Nevertheless I'm unable to create any new contact/customer/supplier/etc with this user. I'm running out of options, I don't know what else to test or where to look.

**EDIT**

Got an answer on the brand new [OpenERP discussion site](http://help.openerp.com/question/480/openerp7-new-user-with-full-rights-unable-to-create-new-partners/) recommending to uncheck the `Portal` user rights for the user. Uncheking it partially worked. The warning still appears but when I click OK, fill the supplier and save, the new supplier is added without errors. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a reported bug that seems to be related to multi-company option selection and user rights.

Go to [multi company Access Denied Document type: Partner, Operation: read](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/1073087) where the bug was reported and is followed up by other users. Hope a patch is created soon.

Answer (score 3):

I really think that's not a bug.

it's a conflict of "Rights" (in Access rules and ACL).

A "Portal or Anonymous" user, is an external user (from the company) and have only some limited rights for accessing some public informations or it can be an exteranl partner which can access his private documents and informations related to his relation with this company.

A normal OpenERP user (*a company employee with some or all rights "let's call it an internal user"*) ***can't be*** and **should not be** in the same time a "Portal or Anonymous" user (with very limited rights), and vice-versa.

Just **uncheck** these two options for an internal OpenERP user.

Comment: Can you add relevant links to help direct how to do these tasks and what the full impact would be?

Comment: Already tried this option days ago, didn't worked for me, but nevertheless thanks, maybe others can benefit from your answer

Comment: Thank you, I've read a lot of things online which wasn't even close to solve this. I had **Portal** and **Public** ticked on Odoo 8. Once again : StackOverflow : 1 - Internet : 0.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I don't think that's a bug.
I got that error with a user when I created an employee linked to this user.
You have to be at least an employee from the society to add a new client.

Link to create a new employee :

```
http://yoururl:PORT/?ts=1369948181483#view_type=kanban&model=hr.employee&menu_id=273&action=328
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when I granted Portal rights to a contact/customer, then when a Quotation is sent (testing), opeing the Quotation yields the error message:

> Access Denied
>
> The requested operation cannot be completed due to security
>   restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.
>
> (Document type: Partner, Operation: read)

However, clicking OK, can get past it and proceed to pay.  This is a major ongoing sort of issue with OPENERP.  It should be fixed by now...

Comment: And just to be sure, I just did a Full BZR Pull on Server/Web/Addons directories so should be fully up to date.  Error repeated even after full server restart.

Comment: What would be the conflict between Access Rules and ACL?  Are they not the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar problem, may solution was to add a record rule for the `Administration / Settings` group, here is how:

1- Go to `Settings->Groups` and select `Administration / Settings`. (Make sure this group is assigned to de new user)

2- Click the `Edit` button and go to the `Rules` tab. (It should be empty)

3- Click the `Add` button, this action open a modal window, click the `Create` button on it.

4- Give the new rule a semantic name - e.g. `Partner: administration settings: see all` - and make sure all the access rights are selected.

5- In the object drop down type `res.partner`, it will allow you to select the object named `Partner` referenced in the error.

6- Click the `Add` button in the `Groups` section and select the `Administration / Settings` group.

7- Finally click the `Save & Close` button and save the group changes by clicking the `Save` button.

Hope this is helpful for beginners in OpenERP. Actually I already have used this solution patter more than once for similar error related to permissions a given user was expected to have.

Answer (score 0):

Its a rules issue. Deactivate the rule Product Template . Rules overrule access writes setup under the user setup. So it looks like users have identical access but these rules bypass your customisations.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should active developer mode, and go to setting/user -> select the user have this error. Then click edit and uncheck public in "Other Extra Rights" section. After that, click save.